# Does Google choose the first two FAQs, or the two most relevant from structured data/schema markup to display on the SERP?

Tags: schema.org, search-results, structured-data, technical-seo

I am adding Schema Markup to my website for the first time. I am implementing FAQs for relevant pages and realize that Google has updated to only show two (2) FAQs to promote competition on the SERP, but if I use the code below indicating more than two (2) FAQs, will Google select what it thinks are the most relevant two (2), or will Google always choose the first two (2) and ignore the rest?

For example, will Google ever choose the 3rd question, or is everything after the second question just ignored?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context" : "https://schema.org",
    "@type" : "FAQPage",
    "mainEntity:" : [
    {
        "@type" : "Question",
        "name" : "What is travel insurance?",
        "acceptedAnswer" : {
            "@type" : "Answer",
            "text" : "Travel insurance is a type of policy that reimburses you for money you lose from no-refundable deposits and payments when something goes wrong on your trip. These problems can range from lost baggage to flight delays to medical problems."
        }
    },
    {
        "@type" : "Question",
        "name" : "What is not covered by travel insurance?",
        "acceptedAnswer" : {
            "@type" : "Answer",
            "text" : "There are common things not covered by travel insurance. Make sure you read a policy's exclusions so you're not caught by surprise later. For example, a travel insurance policy could have medical coverage but exclude pre-existing conditions. So if an existing condition flares up during your trip, the travel insurance policy won't cover it unless you purchased a pre-existing conditions exclusion waiver."
        }
    },
    {
        "@type" : "Question",
        "name" : "How much does travel medical insurance cost?",
        "acceptedAnswer" : {
            "@type" : "Answer",
            "text" : "How much does Travel Health Insurance cost? Travel health insurance costs can vary on several factors, and the rates change constantly. However, a typical plan can range from as little as $4.31 per person per week and go upwards of $100 for a short trip abroad."
        }
    }]
}
</script>
```

Comment: How did you know if Google has updated to only show two (2) FAQs?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur see https://twitter.com/dannysullivan/status/1405914145635983365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How Google Displays FAQ Structured Data

The order that the FAQs are listed in your object will be the order that they appear on the SERP.

Google may only display *the first two*, but I've seen exceptions of this rule. In order for your FAQs to appear your semantic markup must be valid (microformats is allowed too) and meet the [FAQPage Structured Data Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/faqpage):

- Only use `FAQPage` if your page has a list of questions with answers. If your page has a single question and users can submit alternative answers, use `QAPage` instead.
- Don't use `FAQPage` for advertising purposes.
- Make sure each `Question` includes the entire text of the question and make sure each `Answer` includes the entire text of the answer. The entire question text and answer text may be displayed.
- Question and answer content may not be displayed as a rich result if it contains any of the following types of content: obscene, profane, sexually explicit, graphically violent, promotion of dangerous or illegal activities, or hateful or harassing language.
- All `FAQ` content must be visible to the user on the source page.
- If you have FAQ content that is repetitive on your site (meaning, the same question and answer appear on multiple pages on your site), mark up only one instance of that FAQ for your entire site.

---

### Your Example

By running your code through Googles Rich Results Test, we can see that it checks out perfectly fine. After adding this markup to a page, it will appear like this in the results.

[image]

Side note - depending on the authority of your website, your FAQ(s) do not *have* to be marked up in JSON-LD in order for Google to pick them up.

If your FAQs are marked up, Google might include them in "People Also Ask" featured snippet for a given query from any of your FAQ content, or a combination of both *your* content or that of another website.

### Inclusion in "People Also Ask" Featured Snippets

*(This is what I was thinking about before, my apologies...it was late...)*

If your question(s)/answer(s) are of high quality, and are relevant to a search Google may also show them in the "People Also Ask" section on relevant SERPs.

Appearing in these is often desired because FAQs will typically only show up for *Branded* searches (which are most of the time going to be *navigational*).

In these cases, Google does not care about the order in which your FAQ are presented in your structured data, they'll pick whichever one is relevant to the search.

Google may mix and match this content with answers from other sites, or display a question listed on some other site, but include your answer with your page linked in the expanded accordion.

What matters most here is that at least one of your FAQs is highly relevant, matches intent, and is otherwise "a good candidate" for a given search; or even a given search *based* on the user's history.

### About Featured Snippets

Google’s search results sometimes show listings where the snippet describing a page comes before a link to a page, not after as with our standard format. Results displayed this way are called "featured snippets." You might find featured snippets on their own within overall search results, within the "People also ask" section, or along with Knowledge Graph information.

We display featured snippets when our systems determine this format will help people more easily discover what they’re seeking, both from the description about the page and when they click on the link to read the page itself. They’re especially helpful for those on mobile or searching by voice.

Featured snippets commonly contain one listing, but more than one may appear.

Read More: [How Google’s featured snippets work](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9351707#zippy=%2Cwhy-featured-snippets-may-be-removed)

Comment: Could you add some references to support your claims here, or are these opinions?

Comment: @GDVS I blanked and was thinking about "People Also Ask". Answer updated. Lol that would have been a _big_ claim.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. One follow up just for clarification and I will mark this as the accepted answer. You state: "The order that the FAQs are listed in your object will be the order that they appear on the SERP," so it sounds my hunch was correct that under our listing (as opposed to the "People Also Ask"), Google will only ever show the first 2 FAQs? Consequently, the order of the FAQs is of great significance?

Comment: @user577732 To play it safe, yes make sure that the first two that appear in your JSON-LD are the ones that you want shown beneath your result on the SERP. I've seen cases where that has not happened though - particularly, on highly authoritative sites in cases where the 3rd happens to be more relevant to the query than the 2nd.